# how to put variable in html anchor tag?

Tags: php, html

Cant link up the text properly. Got stuck on `<a>` tag..please help.

```
<?php
$string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";
$len=strlen($string);
echo strlen($string) >= 30 ? 
    substr($string, 0, 30) . ' <a href="/*what should I put here*/">[Read more]</a>' : $string;
```

when to click [Read More] it should provide the whole text on the page.

Comment: <?php
$string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";
$len=strlen($string);
echo strlen($string) >= 30 ? 
substr($string, 0, 30) . ' <a href="/*what should I put here*/">[Read more]</a>' : $string;


here is the code I tried...please help

Comment: You need javascript for this. You should Google that "Read more" with "javascript".

Comment: actually i dont want to get javascript for this. can it be done by php only? @Funk Forty Niner

Comment: That's something I never tried before, so I couldn't tell you, sorry. I always used JS/jQuery for stuff like this, because that's all I knew what to use from way back.

Comment: say, $string will take input from user...can you  please provide the javascript for this particular problem? @Funk Forty Niner

Answer (score -1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #more {display: none;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Read More Read Less Button</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
      var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
      var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

      if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
        moreText.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
      }
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the complete code

Comment: he just has to put the onlick() function on the button